# Initial conditions in Second order ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Maybe I have a not good question but to be sure about it I ask it.

For solving second order differential equation like $$x''+ax'+c=f(x)$$(derivatives are respect to $t$)we want two initial conditions $x(0)$ and $x'(0)$.

**My question:**

Is this necessary to have complete derivative of $x$ in $t=0$ or only right or left derivative of $x$ in 0 is enough to solve problem(means that there exist unique solution and we can find  it!) ?

(in two cases first if we assume $x$ should be continuous in this case I think from equation we can conclude that right and left derivative in every point should be equal(of course I don't know what conditions should $f(x)$ have) and second case is that $x$ is not continuous!)

Comment: For forward-in-time solution, the right derivative is enough; for backward-in-time solution, the left derivative is enough. A function $x(t)$ can be a solution in a slightly weak sense even if $x'(0^+) \neq x'(0^-)$.